# Event ID 4013 DNS-Server-Service on Network with Only One Domain Controller/DNS/etc

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows

I'm consulting for a small business that has a single server that handles DC, DNS, DHCP, etc. roles. It is giving the following error with some regularity:
4013 DNS-Server-Service

> The DNS server is waiting for Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) to signal that the initial synchronization of the directory has been completed. The DNS server service cannot start until the initial synchronization is complete because critical DNS data might not yet be replicated onto this domain controller. If events in the AD DS event log indicate that there is a problem with DNS name resolution, consider adding the IP address of another DNS server for this domain to the DNS server list in the Internet Protocol properties of this computer. This event will be logged every two minutes until AD DS has signaled that the initial synchronization has successfully completed.

Any ideas on why?

Comment: Are you usually seeing those after a reboot?

Comment: That seems like a fairly typical problem in a single DC domain. Are you seeing Event ID 2 and Event ID 4 in the DNS Server event log fairly shortly after Event ID 4013? If so, then I don't think there's a serious problem. Several processes run upon reboot; Initialization of the network card, the DC locating itself via DNS, the DC loading the AD DNS zone, AD DS initializing, the DC waiting for inbound replication from partners (which don't exist in a single DC scenario), etc., etc.

Comment: I'd think it was normal too, except that while it does occur during a reboot, it also seems to occur somewhat frequently while the system is up and stable.